# Title for Google pie chart appears but the chart does not appear on the browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, charts, google-visualization

I have written code to represent the expenses of a company for a week from mySQL database dynamically using google pie chart. My code does not have any error. The title of the chart is getting displayed but the chart is not displayed in the browser. Would be glad if you guys helped.

The PHP code used to SELECT the data from the database is as follows:

```
<?php

$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='xxxx';
$db='petrol_bunk';

$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die("Not Connected");
mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or die("DB Not Found");  

$query ="SELECT SUM(`auditing`), SUM(`assests`), SUM(`advertisements`),SUM(`bank_charges`), SUM(`driver_bata`), SUM(`electricity`), SUM(`food`), SUM(`maintenance`), SUM(`printing`), SUM(`salary`), SUM(`office_supplies`), SUM(`taxes`), SUM(`tele_internet`),SUM(`generator`)*AVG(`hsd_price`), SUM(`others`) FROM `daily_expenses` WHERE `date` between date_sub(now(),INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and now();";

$resultPieWeek=mysqli_query($con,$query);?>
```

The script code part is as follows:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
          $( 'ul.nav li' ).on( 'click', function() {
                $( this ).parent().find( 'li.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );
                $( this ).addClass( 'active' );
          });

    });  
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','timeline','table']});


    function drawPieWeekChart(){


        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 
        ['Type of Expenditure', 'Amount'],

                    <?php 

                    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultPieWeek);

                    echo "['Auditing','".$row[0]."'],['Assests','".$row[1]."'], ['Advertisements', '".$row[2]."'],['Bank Charges', '".$row[3]."'], ['Driver Bata', '".$row[4]."'],['Electricity','".$row[5]."'],['Food','".$row[6]."'],['Maintenance','".$row[7]."'], ['Printing','".$row[8]."'],['Salary','".$row[9]."'], ['Office Supplies','".$row[10]."'],['Taxes','".$row[11]."'],['Telephone and Internet','".$row[12]."'],['Petrol for Generator','".$row[13]."'],['Others','".$row[14]."']";
                    ?>
                    ]);


        var options = {
            title: "THIS WEEK's EXPENDITURE"
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieWeek'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

    }


    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawPieWeekChart); 


</script>
```

The HTML code that I used to call the graph is below:

```
<div class="tab-content">

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="weekly_exp">
      <div id="pieWeek"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance guys.I am freaking out here.

Comment: Can you take a look at the console to see if there is any errors ? (f12) Also make sure that the DOM element `pieWeek` is available and loaded when you try to load chart..

Comment: AKA , ensure the Javascript executes **AFTER** the HTML has loaded into the browser..

Comment: I am not getting any errors in the console. The element pieWeek is available too. The title for the chart is getting displayed perfectly.

Comment: Does your query actually returns something? Have you checked if it returns values? Your titles seem to be entered values within the code, the `[row]` values are dynamicly out of a database, check first if this actually returns something. Echo them simply out. If nothing returns, your error is probably within the sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the quotes from the values, they should be numbers, not strings...

```
echo "['Auditing',".$row[0]."],['Assests',".$row[1]."],...
```